# Determine terms for facet fields in solr

Tags: solr, facet, faceted-search, solar

I base on facet.field and I have one situation. In my store i have base products and variants, when I use facet.field I get count with base products and variants:

```
Category:
   Chairs(30) <- this is count of base products and variants
   Tables(20) <- this is count of base products and variants
```

I want to add some terms for facet.field in order to that facet return count only of variants, every product has field like "productType":"baseProduct" or "productType":"variantProduct" 
I want to use those fields.

Any ideas? how can I use this in some query , please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [use `facet.pivot`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-facet.pivot) to get distinct counts for each type:

```
&facet.pivot=productType,category
```

You can also [use the JSON Facet API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/json-facet-api.html) to do two separate facets:

```
{
  base: {
     type: terms,
     field: category,
     domain: { filter: "productType:baseProduct" }
  },
  variant: {
     type: terms,
     field: category,
     domain: { filter : "productType:variantProduct" }
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer but i want to impact on this values "facet_counts":{ "facet_queries":{}, "facet_fields":{ "category":[ "Chairs",28, "Tables",20]}, Can i use some filters? like fq={!tag=pr}productType:baseProduct&facet.field={!ex=pr}category

Comment: In that case you're _explicitly_ saying that you don't want the filter to affect category. If you only want to filter the result set to a single set of documents, using just `fq=productType:baseProduct` and nothing more is enough.

Comment: sorry for late answer. I cant use simple filter query because i want to get all products on my page from solr (Base products and Variants) but I want to impact only on Count number but i want to get all of them on my listing product page. I want to that count will show only count from base products , right now count is amount of Base product and variant.

Comment: In that case you'll have to use the `filter` method as shown on the JSON Facet API example I gave. That will filter the set of documents used only for that particular facet.

Comment: thank you, it could be works but i have older version of solr, i cant use JSON Facet API :(

Comment: Then it's time to schedule an upgrade :-)